# Are there sources for more esoteric data than streets worldwide?

Tags: data

Related to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-to-get-street-data-in-an-importable-format) question.

For example, things like:

- political world map (as polygons)
- cities of the world
- geolocated climate data (avg temp, humidity, rain, as polygons),
- earthquakes,
- hurricanes (as polylines hopefully with strength as z-axis data)
- store location of international chains (mcdonalds, for example)

If you know sources only for specific countries/regions, that is still helpful. Please point out if the source provides only a WMS layer or supplies downloadable data

Answer (score 8):

I'll address your request individually.  All sources provide downloadable data:

> ```
> political world map (as polygons)
> ```

I currently use the [Natural Earth Sovereign States](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/10m-admin-0-sovereignty.zip) dataset for this,

> ```
> cities of the world
> ```

You have a few choices here:

- [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/) aggregates a lot of different data sources, and thus is a little inconsistent.  However, it has a lot of features in it.
- Again, [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-populated-places/) provides data here, in flavours that include [more](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/10m-populated-places.zip) or [less](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/10m-populated-places-simple.zip) towns.  I haven't used this dataset, but I would expect it to be of highly quality given there other products.

> geolocated climate data (avg temp,
>   humidity, rain, as polygons)

For climatic data you cannot go past [WorldClim](http://www.worldclim.org).  It contains raster datasets for [current](http://www.worldclim.org/current) and [past](http://www.worldclim.org/past) climates (and if you're feeling adventurous, even a [future](http://www.worldclim.org/futdown.htm) dataset based on IPCCC models).  It includes monthly data for mean, min and maximum temperatures, precipitation and altitude.  It's a reasonably complex dataset, so it might take a while to understand what's there.

> earthquakes

The USGS provides [yearly earthquake data](http://neic.usgs.gov/neis/epic/kml/index.html) for every year since 1973 in KML format.  Alternative, there is a [catalogue of global earthquakes](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/research/data/centennial.xls) from 1900 to April 2002.  I haven't used either, but their website is full of interesting dataset worth poking around at.

> hurricanes (as polylines
>   hopefully with strength as z-axis
>   data)

For American hurricane tracks, the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration provides an excellent [historical dataset](http://csc-s-maps-q.csc.noaa.gov/hurricanes/data/all_hurtrack.zip).  I am not aware of datasets for other areas.

> store location of international
>   chains (mcdonalds, for example)

This is a bit more difficult.  [AggData](http://www.aggdata.com/) sell (at affordable prices) dataset for hundreds of different chains in the USA.  Historical Walmart store locations in the USA are available [here](http://projects.flowingdata.com/walmart/Walmarts.tar.gz), along with code to visualise them.   Mainitaining a global data-set for these things sounds like a worthy project!

Comment: for hurricanes, also check out the Joint Typhoon Warning Center, in particular the Best Track Archive: http://www.usno.navy.mil/JTWC/

Answer (score 4):

Australian Bureau of Statistics provides downloadable data at http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/2923.0.30.0012006?OpenDocument

Answer (score 3):

In the US, I like to use the geospatial library websites from different universities.  They usually contain some world wide reference layers, and some detailed info on a state or two.  The University of Washington's website is just one example.

http://www.lib.washington.edu/subject/WaStateMaps/dr/elnum.html

You can also download OpenStreetMap data from Cloudmade.

http://cloudmade.com/

Comment: in FL we have http://www.fgdl.org

Answer (score 2):

Geoscience Australia provides WMS access and downloadable data in the following themes at its MapConnect site: http://www.ga.gov.au/mapconnect/

"250K - 1:250 000 scale topographic map data 
GlobalMap - 1:1 million scale topographic map data 
Geology - 1:1 million and 1:2.5 million scale geological map data 
geoMAP - Create a quality PDF map"

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the notes I wrote about the base map server I'm setting up - http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/index.html which discusses the Natural Earth data set which provides countries, cities etc.

For earthquakes try http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/ which provides a variety of formats.

Hurricanes (and other weather) go to http://gis.srh.noaa.gov/ArcGIS/services/AtStormViewer/mapserver/WMSServer?request=getcapabilities&service=wms - WMS only.

Answer (score 2):

Several "original" (and global) sources i'd like to cite :

- GlobCover, global land cover : http://postel.mediasfrance.org/en/PROJECTS/Preoperational-GMES/GLOBCOVER/ and http://ionia1.esrin.esa.int/
- CIESIN global population of the world : http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/gpw/
- CRU  and WorldClim global climatic data : http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/, http://www.worldclim.org/

Answer (score 0):

The USA Census Bureau have a right set of data called the [TIGER lines](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2009/tgrshp2009.html).

- Administrative boundaries
- Political boundaries
- Basic heat map data (crime data, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Global administrative areas can also be found here: [gadm](http://gadm.org/)