# MapQuest License

Tags: api, license, legal

I read the license of Geodata provider (facebook, foursquare...) but I don't understand what it means:

> LICENSE FROM YOU TO MAPQUEST. If you
>   **upload** any data, feedback, ideas,
>   suggestions, content, points of
>   interest (including any points of
>   interest that include Trademarks) or
>   other material to MapQuest
>   (collectively “Your Content”), you
>   **hereby grant MapQuest a perpetual,
>   worldwide, non-exclusive, royalty-free
>   license to access, archive, reproduce,
>   publicly display, translate, modify**
>   the format or the display of,
>   distribute, transmit, stream, cache,
>   overlay, seam, perform, sublicense,
>   and otherwise use Your Content with or
>   without attribution and without
>   financial obligation, in whole or in
>   part, via any method for any purpose.
>   MapQuest makes no assertion of
>   ownership over Your Content, and you
>   retain all intellectual property
>   rights to Your Content, subject to the
>   license you grant to MapQuest above.

For example, I would like to use their data and load it into my geodatabase. Is that allowed?

Comment: it applies to any data you create and use with the Mapquest API - they can also use. (not a lawyer) but google also have this. Mapquest do have an Open API - http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v6.1.0/#top (based on OpenStreetMap data)

Comment: @Mapperz: It seems like [MapQuest uses OSM data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MapQuest), so would data retrieved using the MapQuest API be under [CC BY-SA 2.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/), i.e., the [same license](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) as data retrieved through the OSM API?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, blah blah blah.

What you are reading is the section that applies to you using their APIs to modify *their* content. What this means is that they have *write* APIs that allows you to add POIs into their database and they want to make sure that whatever you modify will be theirs (and they will be allowed to share it with their providers).

What you want is the opposite - to download their data into your GeoDatabase. These APIs are made for content that you will mashup with your own, most of the time, on the fly. They are not designed for bulk download and analysis (they have provisions for "caching", which is a gray area). The terms vary from provider for provider, but I can almost guarantee to you that the answer for most of them (if not all) is *NO*, unless you pay them for a separate license. You have to keep in mind that Mapquest, Facebook and every one else licenses their data from many providers and that allowing this behavior would cannibalize their data providers niche market.

I don't know what you are looking for specifically, but you should probably post a new questions for unencumbered datasets that provide with the specific data that you are looking for. In the past, people have asked for [POI datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10299/poi-datasets-for-north-america) (heck, this was you!), [street datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-to-get-street-data-in-an-importable-format), [elevation datasets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=elevation) and much much more.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks man ! I think that with Facebook and Foursquare, the license authorize the download : "You may cache data you receive through use of the Facebook API in order to improve your application’s user experience, but you should try to keep the data up to date. This permission does not give you any rights to such data".

Comment: Google also gives you "caching", but like a said, it is a gray area. There is a huge difference between adding your results to memcached or redis vs storing it in the GeoDatabase. Besides, they also include provisions for asking you to get rid of the cache. Also remember that it is easy on their end to flag the fact that you are doing bulk downloads, What are you trying to do with the POIs?

Comment: "Also remember that it is easy on their end to flag the fact that you are doing bulk downloads" and the risk ? I search a lot of information on Poi America because i would like product a descriptive mapping.

Comment: The risk? You are violating the agreement. If you are "Joe Schmoe", they probably just block your account and are done with it. If you are bigger, you will probably hear from their lawyers.

Comment: I see this forum : http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=98906 -> >>how do i keep track of it at app level?
save all the data into your local database !! Biggo

Comment: The FB terms of service for their Places API are more liberal than the MapQuest ones (which were referred by you in your question). They used to be more strict about it, but know they just want people to use it and will look the other way - for now.

Comment: It's very cool for me !