# World's roads layer

Tags: shapefile, data, layers, road

Do you know where I can download an updated shapefile of the roads of the World that come from a single source?

I've downloaded the Global Roads Open Access Data Set (gROADS), v1 (1980 – 2010), but this is a compilation from different data souces and cannot compare the data among all countries.

Comment: Why not just acquire the OSM dataset?

Comment: @ThomasHorner Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Trying to see if there were other requirements for the data.  But yeah, might as well throw it in an answer I guess.

Comment: related  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19552/where-can-i-find-road-shapefile-e00-etc-for-the-entire-world

Comment: The main requirements is to be global and from a single source

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: Are you really after a shapefile? the format is limited to 2GB, and it's likely that all the roads of the world won't fit onto a file that small

Comment: What amount of detail do you need? What scale will you be using it at. A truly comprehensive accuate dataset of all the world's roads cannot possibly be from one single source. OSM might be your best bet. Maybe it can be generalized.

Answer (score 5):

OpenStreetMap data might be what you are looking for -- it is somewhat standardized and pretty up-to-date across many parts of the globe.

Check out their wiki for steps on download and converting their datasets.  Then just extract the roads data from there.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data#All_data_at_once

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm afraid OpenStreetMaps doesn't cover many sites of the world